# How to use GrailsCentral with Nexus

Tags: maven, grails, dependencies, nexus, external-dependencies

I want my Grails apps to use repositories hosted by an internal Nexus installation instead of pointing directly to `GrailsCentral()`, `GrailsPlugins()` and `MavenCentral()`. What would be the best strategy to accomplish that? I already tried to create some internal repositories, which proxy other external repositories, but sometimes new dependecies are not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Glen Smith's article on this subject http://blogs.bytecode.com.au/glen/2012/06/04/seriously-offline-grails-going-totally-sans-internet-with-nexus.html

Comment: That is a good an in-depth explanation. But it seems that http://plugins.grails.org/ is currently not a valid repository (moreover, if I try to open it on my browser, I get the Grails initial page). I made my internal Nexus repository work as expected, but pointing to http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/.